# Number of active tasks decline on Spark when using parquet

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr, parquet

I'm running Spark on EMR and reading files from S3. When I read JSON files, the number of active tasks in the cluster remains high for the duration of the entire job. E.g.:

[image]

However, If I change the file type to parquet (it is the ONLY thing I change), the number of active tasks rapidly collapses to the point where I'm only running about 3 in the entire cluster (I.e. I only end up using ~3 nodes).

I have tried setting `spark.default.parallelism` and running a `repartition` after reading in the data. Nothing seems to work.

What is going wrong here? Note that my data is relatively small ~ 150MB (In case that matters).

Comment: Did you check number of partitions  after loading parquet file?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAnugula Yep. 18 partitions - only 3 active tasks. With json I get 18 partitions and ~36 active tasks.